# Read every nth line of data, Read all lines after condition

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a file named Myfile.txt with a header and three rows of data:

```
Header Row1 Row2 Row3

    5.10 10 15
    5.20 20 25
    5.30 30 35
    5.40 40 45
    5.50 50 55
    5.60 60 65
    5.70 70 75
    5.80 80 85
    5.90 90 95
    5.95 10 20
    6.00 25 30
    6.05 35 40
```

I want to read in every 3 lines that increment the first column by .1 and then all lines after the increment to .05, so my output looks like:

```
    5.30 30 35
    5.60 60 65
    5.90 90 95
    5.95 10 20
    6.00 25 30
    6.05 35 40
```

I have the following code but I don't know how to implement the condition, can I get some help doing this?

```
per_line = 3;
every_nth_line = 3;
fmt = [repmat('%*f',1,per_line*(every_nth_line-1)), repmat('%f',1,per_line)];
fid = fopen('Myfile.txt','rt');
datacell = textscan(fid,fmt,'delimiter','\n','HeaderLines',1,'CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid);
C=datacell{1};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
fileID = fopen('Myfile.txt');
mydata = textscan(fileID,'%f%f%f','HeaderLines',2);
findx = (find(abs(diff([mydata{1}(1)-0.1;mydata{1}])-0.1000)<0.0001));
sindx = (find(abs(diff(mydata{1})-0.05)<0.0001))+1;
alldata = [mydata{:}];
C= [alldata(findx(3:3:end),:);alldata(sindx,:)];
fclose(fileID);
```

[diff](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) is used to determine the difference between entries in the first column. [abs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/abs.html) is used to determine equality between floating point numbers within a small difference, and [find](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) is used to return their indexes.

*C* contains:

```
5.3000   30.0000   35.0000
5.6000   60.0000   65.0000
5.9000   90.0000   95.0000
5.9500   10.0000   20.0000
6.0000   25.0000   30.0000
6.0500   35.0000   40.0000
```